# Appium Inspector is not identifying some of the elements on IOS Mobile app

Tags: ios, automation, appium

`React-native` Custom Objects Identification

`Appium` inspector is not able to find the child elements of its parent element.

Could any one please help me out
[image]

Comment: If you still facing issue you can check this link: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63751286/appium-inspector-is-unable-to-locate-the-child-elements-in-ios-element-hierarchy/64351253#64351253)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try another inspector utility macaca developed in node.js**

To install app-inspector, Node.js environment is required.

To **install** it use below command

**$ npm install macaca-cli -g**

Your environment needs to be set up for the particular mobile platforms that you want to view. 
Install Android SDK for Android, Xcode for iOS. Verify the environment with macaca-cli.

**$ macaca doctor**
If you saw **some green log information, it means your platform environment is ready**. Then you can install app-inspector and use it.

**Launch 
$ app-inspector -u YOUR-DEVICE-ID**

iOS
From command line

$ **xcrun simctl list**

The **command above will list all your iOS simulator devices information**. You can find the UDID like XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.

From Xcode
Open your simulator, choose Hardware - devices - manage devices. You will find the identifier in the device information.

Comment: I followed all the steps as you mentioned, but I couldn't launch the View hierarchy of app-inspector.Instead it showed me some errors like the below,

Comment: app-inspector -u DEVICE-ID giving errors.app-inspector -u 02CD8E55-9821-4440-BCFF-BE2FCADF83B0 >> XCTestWD version: 1.3.31
>> Read simulator log at:/var/folders/gf/k9jk5k4j6mx5ddgslwk8xfkc0000gp/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-8C679C95-61C0-4D17-8B8D-6C89B596A352/XCTestWDUITests-31C01D4F-2390-4016-A7CB-5DCA47550746/StandardOutputAndStandardError.txt
>> Read simulator log at: /var/folders/gf/k9jk5k4j6mx5ddgslwk8xfkc0000gp/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-8C679C95-61C0-4D17-8B8D-6C89B596A352/XCTestWDUITests-31C01D4F-2390-4016-A7CB-5DCA47550746/StandardOutputAndStandardError.txt

Comment: Not able to view the hirerachy in the browser by giving localhost:5678