# Appium Inspector is unable to locate the child elements in iOS Element Hierarchy

Tags: react-native, appium, appium-ios

**Apps built on** : React Native 0.62.2

**Tool used for Testing** : Appium v1.17.1

**Issue Description** : The Child Elements in the iOS hierarchy are not getting inspected/located by Appium Inspector.

We are giving IDs to elements using testID and accessibilityLabel properties :

return {
testID: id,
accessibilityLabel: id,
};

But still the appium is not able to identify the elements in the iOS hierarchy.

On Android Element Hierarchy we see the Child elements of the element “ingredient_row_container_radish_wedges”

Android App Source :
[image]

But on iOS we don’t see the child elements of the element “ingredient_row_container_radish_wedges”

iOS App Source :
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a class with following content:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

export function accessibility(id?: string) {
  return Platform.OS === 'android'
    ? { accessible: true, accessibilityLabel: id }
    : { accessible: false, testID: id };
}
```

and import 'accessibility' function where you want to use then
use it as props

<View {... accessibility('ingredient_row_container_radish_wedges')}>