# Unable to inspect/interact with iOS react native app elements in Appium

Tags: react-native, appium, react-native-ios, appium-ios, appium-desktop

I am trying to locate the below highlighted meeting information. However in appium inspector all the elements are combined and shown in a single container.
Three elements highlighted in red has different test id's but when I try to inspect it shows all three as one element. Hence I am not able to interact with any specific element on iOS.
I can inspect the same three elements as different elements in android app. It works fine for android.
p.s - I have also tried to inspect elements using accessibility inspector. the result is the same.

The app is developed in react native for Android and iOS.
Appium desktop version- 1.18.0-2

code snippet-

```
<Card.Content>
          <Title
            accessibilityLabel="testID-meetingTitle"
            testID="testID-meetingTitle"
          >
            {item.name}
          </Title>
          <Text
            style={{ fontSize: 14, lineHeight: 20, color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)" }}
            testID-meetingTitle
            accessibilityLabel="testID-meetingInformation"
            testID="testID-meetingInformation"
          >
            {item.date}
          </Text>
        </Card.Content>
```

Please let me know if there is any solution for the same..

[image]

Comment: Can you update your post with the code for the element that is causing the issue?

Comment: I have now added the code snippet. Could you please suggest ?

Comment: Is it not working with Xpath?

Comment: Check my answer in -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63751286/appium-inspector-is-unable-to-locate-the-child-elements-in-ios-element-hierarchy/64351253#64351253.

Comment: To get access to inner Element in iOS, We need to keep Parent Element 
accessible={false}

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT specify accessibilityLabel for ios
separate props for ios and android like so:

```
export default function testID(id) {
    return Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? {
            accessible        : true,
            accessibilityLabel: id,
        }
        : {
            testID: id,
        };
}
```

and then

```
<Text
    {...otherProps}
    {...testID('testID-meetingInformation')}
/>
```